# Rendering complex Edit View for Questionnaire Answers in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a situation whereby I am trying to recreate a means of recording paper based questionnaire forms using a web interface.

I have a set of database tables in place that I believe are suitable for the purpose but am struggling to find a solution to creating the edit views that will allow a user to manage the answers.

To begin with my table structure looks as follows:
[image: database structure for storing questions and answers]

I have omitted the rest of the database as its not really related to the problem at hand.

Basically, I have different assessments which have a Form Type. A Form Type has a set of questions associated with it. A question has various pieces of data associated with it, namely the expected format of the answer, which can be text, a value, a single or multiple choice. Finally there is a table to record the answers to each question. A question may have multiple entries in here if its a multiple choice.

I have reached the stage whereby I realise that I need to create a set of Answers at render time and display a suitable editor. I need the editor to take into account the format and if its a multiple choice or single choice display a drop down or array of checkboxes.

This is where my intelligence lets me down!

My work in progress code looks as follows:

Firstly, I have a simple class to store all the details of an question and answer for the viewmodel.

```
public class InitialAssessmentAnswerDTO
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<QuestionPossibleAnswer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }

    //different answer types
    public bool AnswerYesNo { get; set; }
    public int? AnswerID { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    public int? AnswerValue { get; set; }
    public string QuestionSection { get; set; }

    public InitialAssessmentAnswerDTO(IEnumerable<QuestionPossibleAnswer> answers)
    {
        PossibleAnswers = answers;
    }

    public InitialAssessmentAnswerDTO()
    {

    }
}
```

I then have a repo method that creates or gets existing answers for a form.

...

```
var form = Context.Forms.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FormName == "Initial Assessment");
        var initialAnswers = new List<InitialAssessmentAnswerDTO>();

        if (form != null)
        {
            var questions = form.QuestionsForForms;

            foreach (var question in questions)
            {
                var a = new InitialAssessmentAnswerDTO();
                a.QuestionID = question.QuestionID;
                a.Question = question.Question.QuestionText;
                a.QuestionSection = question.Question.Section;
                a.Format = question.Question.QuestionAnswerFormat.Format;
                a.PossibleAnswers = question.Question.QuestionPossibleAnswers;

                var answer = ia.InitialAssessmentAnswers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.QuestionID == question.QuestionID);
                if (answer == null)
                {
                    //set some default values here
                }
                else
                {
                    a.AnswerID = answer.id;
                    a.AnswerValue = answer.AnswerValue;
                }
            }
        }
```

So in theory I should end up with a Viewmodel that holds an answer for every question. My problem is I don't know the best way of:

- A - Rendering a list of objects in a manageable way
- B - Displaying a drop down or array of checkboxes

Am I going in the wrong direction with this? Is there an easier way? Am I over-thinking the solution?

Thanks for your time and apologies for the essay like question.

Comment: If you can group your question/answer types in the view (text, yes/no, multiplechoice etc) then this solved relatively simply by use of view models and `EditorTemplates` for each type. I assume by now you have solved it?